# regex remove punct removes non-punctuation characters in R

Tags: regex, r, punctuation

While filtering and cleaning text  in Hebrew, I found that

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", txt)
```

actually removes a relevant character. The character is "ק" and it is located in the "E" spot on the keyboard. Interestingly, the `gsub` function in R removes the "ק" character and then all words get messed up. Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Regular Expressions as used in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> Certain named classes of characters are predefined. Their
>   interpretation depends on the locale (see [locales](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)); the interpretation
>   below is that of the POSIX locale.

Acc. to POSIX locale, `[[:punct:]]`should capture `` ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ ``. So, you might need to adjust your regex to remove only the characters you want:

```
txt <- "!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?@[\\\\^\\]_`{|}~"
gsub("[\\\\!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\^\\]_`{|}~-]", "", txt, perl = T)
```

[Sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMmVpQkNvSjg2R3M) output:

```
[1] ""
```